# How do you use automake 1.14.1

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to use the autoconf toolset to distribute my GPL'd API. I've got the basic distribution working but can't figure out how to do the rest.

1: How do I get a test executable to compile when the user wants to test the distribution. I don't want the files or executable installed?

2: I've got both flex and bison files. The distribution includes the flex and bison output but how do I get the files distributed (and where should I put them in the distribution tree)?

art

Answer (score 1):

1) Include the executable in check_PROGRAMS and it will be built but not installed at make check time.  Alternatively include in noinst_PROGRAMS and it will be built but not installed at make all time.

2) Include your bison and flex output in BUILT_SOURCES.  If that ends up not being sufficient, then just include it in EXTRA_DIST.  I don't think there is a huge convention for where in your tree these live.